# ¿Cómo puedo acceder a wsl2 que utiliza Docker Desktop?

Tags: windows10, wsl, rsync

Quiero transferar un imagen Docker desde el mio PC Windows10 hasta un otro, Fedora, usando rsync. No puedo utilisar WSL, necesito WSL2 como lo contesta el compilador:

```
ubu@DESKTOP-QL4RO3V:/mnt/c/Windows/system32$ docker images                                                                                                                                                                                      
The command 'docker' could not be found in this WSL 1 distro.                                                           
We recommend to convert this distro to WSL 2 and activate                                                               
the WSL integration in Docker Desktop settings.                                                                                                                                                                                                 
For details about using Docker Desktop with WSL 2, visit:                                                                                                                                                                                       
https://docs.docker.com/go/wsl2/
```

Pero creo que hasta que tenga el escritorio Docker, usando WSL2, no sabré cómo acceder a wsl2.

Aquí está mi versión wsl:

```
PS C:\Users\antoi> wsl -l -v
  NAME                   STATE           VERSION
* Ubuntu                 Running         1
  docker-desktop-data    Running         2
  docker-desktop         Running         2
```

Comment: @Juantro17 ¡Corresponde al OP (autor de la pregunta) la traducción al español!

Comment: ahh ok, no sabia.